# iOS: organize a coredata DB

Tags: ios, core-data, entity-relationship

In my app I have 4 json file that I should parse. I show you a single element of json to understand.

```
JSON1 (Area) -> {"id"="...","id-locality"=["...","...","..."], "name"="..."}
JSON2 (Nation) -> {"id"="...", "name"="..."}
JSON3 (Provence) -> {"id"="...", "name"="..."} 
JSON4 (Locality) -> {"id"="...", "name"="..."}
```

As you can see JSON1 "Area" can have multiple values for locality.
I created 4 entity in this way, but I'm not sure, about what type of relationship I should to use between Area and Locality identities. I have this doubt because Locality is an identity for all locality and not only for Area identity.

My prospect is this

[image]

can you help me to understand?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Area has many Localities, and a Locality belongs to a single Area:

[image]

Also, don't use `id` for identifiers, you'll get clashes with Core Data's internal `id` attribute, use a specific name for your id as I've shown in my diagram.

**Edited following comment**

If a Person also has localities:

[image]

And now you also have an implied link between Person and Area.

Comment: ok I understand but locality is not inside area, locality entity is for all locality, for the entire json; in this way it seems that locality is inside area json

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that. Localities are related to Areas. I can't see how one thing is 'inside' another.

Comment: No ok do not consider my last comment, I was confusing. But can I use Locality for another identity in the same way? For example I have Area and another identity called "People" that have inside an array of locality as Area. Can I use the same identity to manage all?